# Omnet++ How to average/max/min some metric over modules?

Tags: omnet++

I have two modules, say M1 and M2. M1 is a simple module, and emits a (long) signal "Signal1". M2 is a compound module, comprising many M1 modules. Now, I want to get the maximum mean value of the Signal1 values of every M1 module.

Using @statistic at M1 level generates many scalars as a result, and I cannot get the maximum. But using it at M2 level, aggregates the signals, and I cannot distinguish among different M1 modules.

```
simple M1
{
    parameters:
        @signal[Signal1](type="long");

        // M1 level statistic
        @statistic[MyStatistic](source=Signal1); record=??);
}

network M2
{
    parameters:
        // M2 level statistic
        @statistic[MyStatistic](source=Signal1); record=??);
    submodules:
        m1[2]: M1;
}
```

For example, let's say that M2 has two M1 modules, M1_1 and M1_2. M1_1 produces a mean value of 1.5 and M1_2 produces a mean value of 2.5. I want 2.5 as the @statistic result. Is this possible with @statistic?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never mind. I found out that this can be achieved in the Datasets view computing a new scalar. It is explained in the [tic toc example](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part7/#75-analyzing-the-results).